# Force SPA route navigation to return 200

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, url-routing

I published my website (a SPA made with vue) to Github-Pages. This website uses "history mode", so the # does not appear when navigating to a different "page".

When direct URL navigation (user types `website.com/downloads` for example) or a refresh while not on the root page happens, the website tries to display 404.html.

When the 404.html loads, it redirects to the homepage, passing the route name taken from the URL:

```
  <script>
    const segment = 1;
    //Gets the relative path and the hash of the URL.
    sessionStorage.redirect = location.pathname.split('/').slice(0, 1 + segment).join('/');
    sessionStorage.hash = location.hash;

    //Forces the navigation back to the main page, since it's the only entry point that works.
    location.replace('/' + location.pathname.slice(1).split('/').slice(segment).join('/'));
  </script>
```

For the user, it is a bit noticeable, but it will display the correct page.
But while loading, it will report a 404 in the network tab, which could cause issues in integrations with other websites.

Is there anyway to fake a 200 response when loading these pages?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical issue with Single Page Applications using history mode (history.pushState) to simulate a full URL so that a page isn’t reloaded when the URL changes.

Since vue.js is an SPA framework, it means there is only one HTML and  tag containing the “app” id. Due to this disadvantage, Google bots would not be able to read the content of a particular landing page and your website might not get the higher rankings. To make Google bots read the content, you can use two method, “Pre-rendering” and “Server-side rendering.”

Also you can try using routing in `<li>` and `<a>` tags and buttons instead of href=“/path”. Using a router link makes page navigation very fast and it benefits the SEO of your website as well.

Comment: Thanks Nina, you gave me an idea. I'm going to add skeleton html pages, redirecting to my actual routes.